# Docking Station for Surface Pro 3 and 13" MacBook Pro

Tags: docking-stations

Is there a docking station that is compatible with both 13" MacBook Pro (2015 model A1502) and a Surface Pro 3?

I am looking for one that has
1. Connectivity up to two monitors (DVI/HDMI/VGA)
2. Ethernet adapter
3. 1 USB Port
4. Portable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugable UD-3900 USB 3.0 Universal Docking Station is working great for me.

This dock has drivers available to recognize it under both Windows 10, and Mac OS.

The dock connects via USB 3.0 cable and is preferable in my situation since both of the computers I am using lack the latest USB C ports.

I got it around US $125.00 that was also well within my budget.